# How to save data in json or any other file format for the further use by JavaScript

Tags: javascript, database, file, web, local-storage

i am trying to make a tracker application, which include the daily entry inside the file.
what i am trying to do is, I want to save the data on some external file (each time i update the entry), so i can easily access data from that file every-time I open the application.

For example : if I am tracking the height of the plant i am growing, so i will use excel to store date and the height of the plant on the respective day and every time i open excel old data is there as well as i can also update new entries in the excel.

Is there any way to do this kind of thing in JavaScript. I am new to this stuff hope you can help me!
looking forward to your suggestions.

Answer (score 0):

If you ask, can you do it with the front-end JS the answer is "NO". Otherwise you can use NodeJS, for example, and save the file on the server side (the back-end).

Other thing is that you better use some datebase for storing the information, because it is easyer to search, update and delete data from it, Excel is not optimized for that, I don't say you can't do it, but is not smart idea.

Comment: Thank you for your response sir, I was just giving example about the excel; i am not going to actually  use that. i will note the key points from your suggestion. thank you once again!